# How can we determine if a system is time invariant or not?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, signal-theory

I am trying to figure out if the system in the diagram (part a) is time knvariant or not. When the input is shifted the output is shifted as well, so I am thinking the system is time invariant, but I wanted to ask for help to get more concrete proof.

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For continuous time:**

A system is time-invariant, if the coefficients of the differential equation describing the system are constants. That is, they don't depend on time.
$$\ddot{y}+2\dot{y}+8=0 \: \: \: \: \: \text{time-invariant}$$
$$\ddot{y}+2t\dot{y}+8t=0 \: \: \: \: \text{time-variant} $$

**For discrete time:**

A system is time-invariant, if the coefficients of the difference equation describing the system are constants.
$$y(n+2) = -2y(n+1)-8 \: \: \: \: \text{time-invariant}$$
$$y(n+2) = -2ny(n+1) -8n \: \: \: \: \text{time-variant} $$

In your exercise, the system is described through the system's impulse response \$h(n)\$ and is clearly time-invariant.